# Vectorization of this Numpy double loop

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

How can I vectorize the following double-loop?

I have one N by A matrix and one N by B matrix, where A and B may differ and N is much smaller than A and B. I want to produce an A by B matrix as follows, but ideally without the loops:

```
import numpy as np

def foo(arr):
    # can be anything - just an example so that the code runs
    return np.sum(arr)

num_a = 12
num_b = 8
num_dimensions = 3

a = np.random.rand(num_dimensions, num_a)
b = np.random.rand(num_dimensions, num_b)

# this is the loop I want to eliminate:
output = np.zeros( (num_a, num_b) )
for i in xrange(num_a):
    for j in xrange(num_b):
       output[i,j] = foo(a[:,i] - b[:,j])
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First vectorise `foo()`, i.e. modify `foo()` in a way that it can correctly operate on an array of shape `(N, A, B)`, returning an array of shape `(A, B)`.  This step is usually the difficult one.  How this is done entirely depends on what `foo()` does.  For the given example, it's very easy to do:

```
def foo(arr):
    return np.sum(arr, axis=0)
```

Now, use [broadcasting rules](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to create a `(N, A, B)` array containing all the vector differences, and pass it to `foo()`:

```
foo(a[:, :, np.newaxis] - b[:, np.newaxis])
```

Comment: Thanks, I've learned a lot from this. Also incredible how much faster the vectorized version is on my full problem. 231 seconds before, 2 seconds after!