# How to vectorize this loop difference in numpy?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, linear-algebra

I feel like there should be a quick way of speeding up this code.  I think the answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299891/vectorization-of-this-numpy-double-loop), but I cannot seem to get my problem in that format.   The underlying problem that I am attempting to solve is find the point wise difference in terms of the parallel and perpendicular components and create a 2d histogram of these differences.

```
out = np.zeros((len(rpbins)-1,len(pibins)-1))
tmp = np.zeros((len(x),2))
for i in xrange(len(x)):
    tmp[:,0] = x - x[i]
    tmp[:,1] = y - y[i]

    para = np.sum(tmp**2,axis=-1)**(1./2)
    perp = np.abs(z - z[i])

    H, _, _ = np.histogram2d(para, perp, bins=[rpbins, pibins])
    out += H
```

Comment: I mainly taged it because of Mr. E's comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299891/vectorization-of-this-numpy-double-loop): "I've tagged this with matlab as there may be a simple solution that matlab users know about, and more often then not there's a corresponding function in Numpy"  Sorry I was not suppose to.

Comment: fair enough on the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vectorizing things like this is tricky, because to get rid of a loop over `n` elements you have to construct an array of `(n, n)`, so for large inputs you are likely to get a worse performance than with a Python loop. But it can be done:

```
mask = np.triu_indices(x.shape[0], 1)
para = np.sqrt((x[:, None] - x)**2 + (y[:, None] - y)**2)
perp = np.abs(z[:, None] - z)
hist, _, _ = np.histogram2d(para[mask], perp[mask], bins=[rpbins, pibins])
```

The `mask` is to avoid counting each distance twice. I have also set the diagonal offset to `1` to avoid including the `0` distances of each point to itself in the histogram. But if you don't index `para` and `perp` with it, you get the exact same result as your code.

With this sample data:

```
items = 100
rpbins, pibins = np.linspace(0, 1, 3), np.linspace(0, 1, 3)
x = np.random.rand(items)
y = np.random.rand(items)
z = np.random.rand(items)
```

I get this for my `hist` and your `out`:

```
>>> hist
array([[ 1795.,   651.],
       [ 1632.,   740.]])
>>> out
array([[ 3690.,  1302.],
       [ 3264.,  1480.]])
```

and `out[i, j] = 2 * hist[i, j]` except for `i = j = 0`, where `out[0, 0] = 2 * hist[0, 0] + items` because of the `0` distance of each item to itself.

---

**EDIT** Tried the following after tcaswell's comment:

```
items = 1000
rpbins, pibins = np.linspace(0, 1, 3), np.linspace(0, 1, 3)
x, y, z = np.random.rand(3, items)

def hist1(x, y, z, rpbins, pibins) :
    mask = np.triu_indices(x.shape[0], 1)
    para = np.sqrt((x[:, None] - x)**2 + (y[:, None] - y)**2)
    perp = np.abs(z[:, None] - z)
    hist, _, _ = np.histogram2d(para[mask], perp[mask], bins=[rpbins, pibins])
    return hist

def hist2(x, y, z, rpbins, pibins) :
    mask = np.triu_indices(x.shape[0], 1)
    para = np.sqrt((x[:, None] - x)[mask]**2 + (y[:, None] - y)[mask]**2)
    perp = np.abs((z[:, None] - z)[mask])
    hist, _, _ = np.histogram2d(para, perp, bins=[rpbins, pibins])
    return hist

def hist3(x, y, z, rpbins, pibins) :
    mask = np.triu_indices(x.shape[0], 1)
    para = np.sqrt(((x[:, None] - x)**2 + (y[:, None] - y)**2)[mask])
    perp = np.abs((z[:, None] - z)[mask])
    hist, _, _ = np.histogram2d(para, perp, bins=[rpbins, pibins])
    return hist

In [10]: %timeit -n1 -r10 hist1(x, y, z, rpbins, pibins)
1 loops, best of 10: 289 ms per loop

In [11]: %timeit -n1 -r10 hist2(x, y, z, rpbins, pibins)
1 loops, best of 10: 294 ms per loop

In [12]: %timeit -n1 -r10 hist3(x, y, z, rpbins, pibins)
1 loops, best of 10: 278 ms per loop
```

It seems that most of the time is spent instantiating new arrays, not doing actual computations, so while there is some efficiency to scrape off, there really isn't much.

Comment: You sir are a gentleman and scholar.  You are correct about the memory usage, but your masking is very helpful.  Thank you from another San Diagoian... Diagan... Diegoist... :D

Comment: You are still doing double computation on the `sqrt` step.  I suspect you can do a bit better both on memory and on run time if you do the masking before taking the square root.

Comment: @tcaswell Just tried it, and there is indeed some, but not much, see my edit.

Comment: Another micro-opt: you can use `hypot` instead of the `sqrt(a**2+b**2)`  It probably won't have much effect here, though, because that's not where most of the time is being spent..

Comment: Apparently another reminder that ram is in fact slow.  Sorry for sending you off an a wild goose chase.