# Numpy: np.where function given argmax

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to perform this function on two 2D numpy arrays:
Step 1: Find `np.argmax(b, axis=1)` indices.
Step 2: Find `b[indices] > a[indices]`
Step 3: Return value in a 2D Boolean array.

I tried this:

```
np.where((b>a)&np.argmax(b,axis=1).reshape((3,-1)), True, False)
```

but no dice. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should the boolean array have the same shape as `a` and `b` or should it be 1D with length `len(a)`?  I'm having trouble understanding your desired output.

Comment: Can you explain this a little more? "For the max value in a row in b, `b > a == True`. Otherwise, `False`."

Comment: @askewchan: Yes, the same shape. Sorry.

Comment: It's still not clear to me I'm afraid. I think it would be helpful here if you gave some expected input and output values.

Comment: @MrE: Think more the output of the `np.where` function, except that only `output[0,1]` is true, as `0.75183753` is both the maximum value of its row in `b`, AND it is greater than the corresponding value in a (i.e., `a[0,1`). Clearer?

Comment: @NoobSaibot I think my answer now does what you are after

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your comments my best understanding is:

```
output = (np.max(b,axis=1)[...,None] == b) & (b > a)
```

Where we make use of Numpy broadcasting to do the "is the maximum of its row in `b`" part:

```
np.max(b,axis=1)[...,None] == b
```

Or perhaps clearer:

```
np.max(b,axis=1)[...,np.newaxis] == b
```

Comment: But could you please explain a bit more the "[...,None]" part? What sorcery is that?

Comment: Excellent, glad it helped! This is [a good overview](http://scipy-lectures.github.com/intro/numpy/numpy.html#broadcasting) of the broadcasting sorcery. [Here's my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299891/vectorization-of-this-numpy-double-loop) where I first learned about the broadcasting rules - [`np.newaxis` can/should be used instead of `None`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944863/numpy-should-i-use-newaxis-or-none). It's a very useful trick.