# Numpy array to replace a for loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

Let's say I have an array A[i,j] and I want to compute a new quantity B[i,j] by doing something like:

```
for i in arange(1, n):
    B[i,j+1] = a*A[i-1,j] + b*A[i,j]+ c*A[i+1,j]
```

What numpy functionality can I use to turn this into a pure array operation?

I was thinking of np.cumprod but it's unclear how to incorporate the coefficients into the calculation.

A.shape will be (n+1, j).

Answer (score 2):

Define `A_left = A[:-2, :]`, `A_middle = A[1:-1, :]` and `A_right = A[2:, :]`

Then `B = a*A_left + b*A_middle + c*A_right`

Comment: I think the assignment part would be `B[1:-1]  = ..`.

Comment: Yes, but actually the question is kind of ill-posed since when i is n-1, OP's last line raises an IndexError.

Comment: It's because OP most probably has A as `n+1` as the number of rows to account for `A[i+1,j]`.

Comment: Possible, but not sure :) hence "kinf of ill-posed". Good point, I've just asked for A.shape in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind a bit of signal processing, you could have a generic solution (generic in the sense where you could assign more elements alongside `a`, `b` and `c` for scaling element from `A`) using [`signal.convolve2d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html).

This would be similar to this [`other solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30215273/3293881) where the theory of convolution as related to such cases is dealt with in a bit more detailed manner. The implementation would look like this -

```
from scipy import signal

B = np.zeros_like(A)

kernel = np.array([a,b,c])[::-1,None]
B[1:-1]  = signal.convolve2d(A, kernel, boundary='symm', mode='valid')
```